Linux file access on external drive using Windows 10
I have multiple machines (3 Windows 10 and 1 Ubuntu Bionic Beaver).
I back them up, or back up files/folders using drag and drop.
The external drive is all NTFS and is not set up as a NAS device.  Everything works as expected except when I'm on the Windows 10 machines the folders and files I created on the Linux machine don't show up.
When I plug back into the Linux machine they're there and are all OK.  I tried changing the access rights to Samba; but, apparently it isn't installed and now that Bionic Beaver is out of LTS I'm not sure how to fix it.
Is there a way from Windows I can make the Linux folders accessible and behave normally?


Unless it's on a 32-bit PC, update Ubuntu to at least 20.04, which has 6 more years, under expanded maintenance (free https://ubuntu.com/pro). 2. Older versions of Linux may have issues writing to NTFS using fuse.


"I have a question which is similar in nature."  To what?

I suggest you upgrade Ubuntu to a supported release ASAP. Meanwhile, at the very least, apply for extended support (ESM) so you get security updates. RE: your issue the answer below says it all.

The files on your external NTFS drive are neither "Linux" nor "Windows" files.
There is nothing about the files there that would indicate the originating machine. However, if your Windows OS has not been completely shut down, as happens with Fast Startup enabled, Windows remounts the NTFS file system using its saved state info when it's restarted, and whatever may have transpired on the drive in the meantime is lost.

Exactly. That's why we say that when dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must.
